# Issues with Android's Mediaplayer lib

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have some pretty standard code to run an MP3, but it takes like 2 seconds to play it.  This app is very simple.  This app should play a 1-2 second sound.  Also, is there a way to buffer the mp3 at app's load into the RAM or something so it can play very quickly(w/o delay)?  Please help!

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
    }


    public void playSound(View v)throws Exception{
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.john_cena);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        //mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        Log.d("1234FIND", "STOP RELEASE RESET");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the slight delay as the media file is loaded, you should prepare your media player instance ahead of time. There's a delay while your media file is loaded and prepared for playback. You have a few options:

- Continue to use `MediaPlayer.create()`, but do so sooner, before you're ready to call `playSound()`. In the simple example you provided, try calling `MediaPlayer.create()` in the `onCreate()` method.
- You could also use the `prepareAsync()` and `setOnPreparedListener()` methods to prepare the media file in the background and set a notification when it is ready. This is more complicated but provides you with more control and a better user experience. If you need to load a large file, this is the best way to make it work. Small audio files probably aren't as big of a deal.
- If you're going to play the same media file over and over again, you don't need to release the MediaPlayer right away. If you don't reset or release, the media will still be in memory and can play again immediately. But be sure to call `release()` when you're definitely done, and in the lifecycle events such as `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

[See the documentation for details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29).

To get it to play for a few seconds and then stop, use Android's CountDownTimer:

```
// Will call onFinish() after 2 seconds. Second parameter is 
// for onTick() which we don't need and can ignore.
new CountDownTimer(2000, 2000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         // Do nothing...
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mediaPlayer.stop();  
         // Decide here if you need to prepare a new clip
         // or release the media player
     }

}.start();
```

Here is a complete example:

```
package com.example.matthew.somediaplayer;

import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "TEST";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isMediaPlayerPrepared = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
                    playSound();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "In onResume()");
        createAndPrepareMediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "In onStop()");
        mediaPlayer.release();
        isMediaPlayerPrepared = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        Log.d(TAG, "In onPause()");
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void createAndPrepareMediaPlayer() {
        Log.d(TAG, "In createAndPrepareMediaPlayer()");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        if(isMediaPlayerPrepared == false) {
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Media player is prepared.");
                        isMediaPlayerPrepared = true;
                        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
                Log.d(TAG, "Beginning to prepare media player.");
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void playSound() {

        Log.d(TAG, "In playSound()");
        if( isMediaPlayerPrepared ) {
            // Will call onFinish() after 2 seconds. Second parameter is
            // for onTick() which we don't need and can ignore.
            new CountDownTimer(2000, 2000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // Do nothing...
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In onFinish()");
                    // We can't call a method like pause on an unprepared MediaPlayer instance.
                    if( isMediaPlayerPrepared ) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Media player isn't prepared, and isn't allowed to pause.");
                    }
                }

            }.start();

            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0); // set to beginning of track (if not already)
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting to play a sound.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where should prepareAsync() go?  In the oncreate/resume/start methods?

Comment: It depends on your application, but I might use onResume() to prepare and onPause() to release.